# `dot2tex` needs root access to work?

Tags: dot2texi

I am currently having an issue when trying to compile some LaTeX with a dot2tex environment : I get an error saying

```
Opening dot2tex stream test-dot2tex-fig1.dotTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.local/bin/dot2tex", line 7, in <module>
    from dot2tex.dot2tex import main
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dot2tex/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    __version__ = d2t.__version__
AttributeError: module 'dot2tex' has no attribute '__version__'
```

when trying to compile with `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex` : I don't have the figure in the produced pdf.
However, if I add `sudo` before that, the command works and the pdf is produced correctly.

Does anyone know how I can solve that problem ?

Here is a minimal code that produces the error :

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{dot2tex}[dot,mathmode,scale = 0.5]
digraph G {
node [shape="circle"];
a [label = "a"];
b [label = "b"];
b -> a ;
}
\end{dot2tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you install `dot2tex`? This looks like you have two installations: one as user, which is broken and one working as root. Try removing all `dot2tex` installations and then do one `pip install dot2tex`.

Comment: I did a pip uninstall dot2tex and then reinstall : the bug was still there. Should I do something more to uninstall ?

Comment: Did you use python2 or python3? I get the errors with python3 but if I install `dot2tex `with `pip2 install --user dot2tex` it works.

Comment: [dot2tex](https://github.com/kjellmf/dot2tex) seems pretty much abandoned and [looking for a new maintainer](https://github.com/kjellmf/dot2tex/issues/58) since 2017.

Comment: I get no error and the expected output.

Comment: Doing it with python2 seems to have fixed it - I used python 3.6. Thanks !

Comment: @egreg which python version are you using?

Comment: @DG' `python --version` issues 2.7.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dot2tex` seems to broken for python 3. You have to use python 2 instead:

- Uninstall `dot2tex` for python 3: `$ pip3 uninstall dot2tex`
- Install `dot2tex` for python 2: `$ pip2 install dot2tex`